# No SPIFFS data upload in Arduino IDE 2.0.0-rc3 (ESP32 & TTGO) - Ubuntu

Tags: esp32, spiffs, arduino-ide-2

I tried adding ***esp32fs.jar*** to ***/home/myname/Arduino/tools/ESP32FS/tool*** (and a few other places as it looked likely that the jar file wasn't loading).  I've definitely got the correct board selected, and can upload Sketches.  I can also run the demo that writes to SPIFFS.

But the Tools menu doesn't have an option for ***ESP32 Sketch data upload***.

Is SPIFFS data upload not available so far in V2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FS upload plugins for ESP are not available in IDE 2 yet (2022-01-07).

IDE 2.0 doesn't run on Java so it can't use the java plugins of the IDE 1. You have to use IDE 1 for FS upload and exception decoder until new plugins are written for IDE 2.

It is tracked here: https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/issues/58

Answer (score 3):

I've created a utility that provides a web-based ESP32 interface for

- OTA
- File system formatting
- FS directory listing
- File uploading
- File editing
- File deletion

It can be found at https://github.com/palmerr23/ESP32-OTA-and-File-Manager

Comment: ESP32-OTA-and-File-Manager does not yet support FFAT, a good start, but 10 months later still to be done? You should point that out in the above.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Timothy, I've changed the FFAT status to "Not implemented" as the utility isn't as necessary as before now that Arduino 2.X has file upload capability. If you want to do the work, please feel free to create a pull request.